# If you block a player, can they see if you're online or not?

Tags: smite

Currently, Smite has two statuses "Online" and "Do Not Disturb", but no "Appear Offline" option.

Does anyone know if the "Block Player" functions like it does for Steam, in the sense that you "Appear Offline" to that player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested it out with a friend. You appear completely offline, and the person being blocked has no indication that they've been blocked.